# Ideas to prove an inequality

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

In my computations, it will be great to find this form of inequality : Find a function F such that :

$\vert x_{1}x_{2}\vert ^{-\alpha} \leq F(x_{1}-x_{2})$

with $\alpha \geq 1$

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific domain for the x’s?  You’re not going to find such an inequality in general.

Comment: yes ! $ x_{i} \in [0,T] $

Comment: There’s no way.  To see this, let the two x’s be equal, and let them go to zero. The right side would be a single value, while the left side is unbounded.

Comment: You think is it possible to have F(linear combination of $x_{i}$) ?

Comment: No, because you can always pick a linear combination that stays zero, while the left side is unbounded.